# Using If statements in a select menu in BASH

Tags: bash

I did some research on making a menu and wanted to have some text displayed depending on the option selected by the user.

I made the same script with case and it functions perfectly. Does anyone have any ideas why this script is only outputting the value for monday?

```
select day in monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday;
do

if [ $day==monday ]; then
echo "need a lot of coffee"
        elif [ $day==tuesday ]; then
        echo "need even more coffee"
        elif [ $day==wednesday ]; then
        echo "need something stronger"
        elif [ $day==thursday ]; then
        echo "need tequila"
        elif [ $day==friday ]; then
        echo "regret thursday"
        elif [ $day==saturday ]; then
        echo "go for a run"
        else
        echo "try not to think about tomorrow"
fi

done
```

I have tried doing

```
select day in monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday;
do
echo $day <--- to see what the value contained here is and it is outputting whichever option is selected but the if statement only outputs the echo of monday.
if [ $day==monday ]; then
echo "need a lot of coffee"
        elif [ $day==tuesday ]; then
        echo "need even more coffee"
        elif [ $day==wednesday ]; then
        echo "need something stronger"
        elif [ $day==thursday ]; then
        echo "need tequila"
        elif [ $day==friday ]; then
        echo "regret thursday"
        elif [ $day==saturday ]; then
        echo "go for a run"
        else
        echo "try not to think about tomorrow"
fi

done
```

Comment: Because you need spaces around `==` to make it a comparison (like this, it's just a long string, which is always true).

Comment: Thank you very much pmf that took care of that. My apologies for not recognizing that. I appreciate your time very much.

Comment: If you prepend your script with a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) (according to your [tag:bash] tag, this could be `#!/bin/bash`), and then paste the script into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/), you can get answers of this kind yourself.

Comment: Don't use `==` with `[`. Use `=`, or use `[[` if you want to use `==`.

Comment: Better yet, use a `case` statement instead of a long `if-elif` statement.

Answer (score 1):

The `[` command requires `==` be passed a separate argument; it will not parse an *single* argument like `$day==monday` as a comparison expression. (As an aside, the "correct" operator to use with `[` is `==`. `bash` allows it, but if you really want to use `==`, you should use `bash`'s `[[` command as well.

```
if [ "$day" = monday ]; then
    ...
```

Better than a long `if` statement, though, would be a `case` statement in this situation.

```
case $day in
    monday) echo "need a lot of coffee" ;;
    tuesday) echo "need even more coffee" ;;
    wednesday) echo "need something stronger" ;;
    thursday) echo "need tequila" ;;
    friday) echo "regret thursday" ;;
    saturday) echo "go for a run" ;;
    sunday ) echo "try not to think about tomorrow"
esac
```